# How to set field automatically from generic type?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface and a type:

```
interface IUserAction<T, P> {
    readonly type: T;
    readonly payload: P;
}

export type UserAction<T, P> = IUserAction<T, P>;
```

I also have an enum `UserActions`:

```
export enum UserActions {
    SetCountry = 'SetCountry',
};
```

Now I want to create a variable `action` reflecting this type:

```
const action: UserAction<UserActions.SetCountry, SetCountryActionPayload> = {
            payload: {countryId: Country.Usa}
        };
```

I see the error:

```
Property 'type' is missing in type...
```

Which seems to be reasonable, as I added type manually to each action before.

I wonder though, is it possible to set `type` field to be equal to `SetCountry`, so that not to have to enter it in addition to first generic type provided?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that UserActions.SetCountry is not a type, it's just an enum member of type UserActions. So what you are trying to do doesn't really make sense.

What you would need to do is this:

```
const action: UserAction<UserActions, SetCountryActionPayload> = {
            type: UserActions.SetCountry,
            payload: {countryId: Country.Usa}
        };
```

Where UserActions is actually the generic type you need to define the generic field type correctly. Unfortunately I can't see a way you could have typescript guess which member of UserActions you want to use.